# is it really necessary to use the public key to send erc20 tokens?

Tags: solidity, web3js, transactions, erc-20, web3.py

It is evident that the private key is the fundamental piece of everything, for that reason I wonder, why we need to include the public key in the transactions, why does the private key not do the whole process by itself? If only the private key is needed to access the funds without depending on the public key, why on the contrary, do we need to include the public key in transactions?

Comment: Can you include a piece of code? and comment the line you have questions about, Im not sure about the scope of your question

Comment: An ERC-20 token is a smart contract, which maps Ethereum accounts ("address" types, obtained from a private key using elliptic curve cryptography) to token balances (of type "uint256"). You can't have a ledger without accounts (what you referred to as "public keys"). Consider reading more about ERC-20 and Ethereum in general, and then circle back with a more specific question if you have one.